# How to using INNER JOIN if one table is empty or no data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables; `room` and `reservation`.

data on `room`

```
id_room | name_room | available_room
1         Class3      6
2         Class2      8
3         Class1      6
```

data on `reservation` is empty

```
id_reservation | id_room | reserved_qty | checkin_date | checkout_date
1
2
3
```

If the guest wants to book a room, the website will display all the available room during data on table `reservation` is empty (like table above), but, if there is data on table `reservation` then the website will show remaining quantity of room (result from reduction between `room.available_room` `reservation.reserved_qty` (`room.available_room` - `reservation.reserved_qty`)) according to the date of booking and date already booked (`checkin_date` and `checkout_date`).

Comment: Why do you have rows in `reservation` that are empty? Shouldn't there just be no row at all? What do these rows mean? They are not even linked to any room.

Comment: @Thilo the `reservation` table appears to have an `id_room` field, which presumably could be used to join back to `room`.

Comment: What does 'available room' mean?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Exactly, and that would presumably be a NOT NULL foreign key. So I don't understand why the rows are empty like that.

Comment: in the first time table `reservation` is empty, why?, because it is a new reservation table and no guests are booked, so, table `reservation` to store data from guest input are booked.

Comment: @Juniantoじゅにあんと So are you saying these records might be partially populated, but the quantity field is empty?

Comment: @Strawberry:  'available room' taked from `room` table

Comment: Surely a room is either available, or it isn't.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: `reserved_qty` is quantity of room booked, and `available_room` is maximum total quantity of room. eg: I want to reserv a Class1 on 15 Jan 2016 (checkin) to 20 Jan 2016 (checkout) with quantity 2 rooms. the record i've inputed stored in `reservation` table: `id_room` = 3, `reserved_qty` = 2, `checkin_date` = 15 Jan 2016, and `checkout_date` = 20 Jan 2016. So if other guest want to book at the same day with me, available room can booked = 4 (subtraction from `available_room` is 6 and `reserved_qty` is 2)

Comment: @Strawberry: room is either available

Comment: Your sample input is confusing, but that aside it would have helped a lot if you showed us what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you would have "defective" rows in the `reservation` table where the `id_room` column is `NULL`.  But that doesn't change the proposed solution, since those defective rows would simply be disregarded, since a `NULL` value for `id_room` would never successfully join anything.

What you want is an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, so that the lack of a reservation doesn't prevent a room from appearing in the result.

```
SELECT room.id_room
     , room.name_room
     , room.available_room - SUM(COALESCE(reservation.reserved_qty, 0)) AS remaining_rooms
    FROM room
        LEFT OUTER JOIN reservation
            ON room.id_room = reservation.id_room
    WHERE
        checkin_date IS NULL OR
        @day BETWEEN checkin_date AND checkout_date
    GROUP BY room.id_room, room.name_room;
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Thilo is sensible, since you might not really have records in the `reservation` table which are just sitting there emtpy.  But if you are, one way to deal with "empty" data would be to use the `COALSECE()` function when computing the difference:

```
SELECT r1.id_room, r1.name_room,
    r1.available_room - COALESCE(r2.reserved_qty, 0) AS numAvailable
FROM room r1
    INNER JOIN reservation r2
    ON r1.id_room = r2.id_room
```